# how to evaluate String to identify duplicate keys

Tags: json, groovy

I have an input string in groovy which is not strictly JSON.

```
String str = "['OS_Node':['eth0':'1310','eth0':'1312']]"
```

My issue is to identify the duplicate "eth0" . I tried to convert this into map using `Eval.me()`, but it automatically removes the duplicate key "eth0" and gives me a Map.

What is the best way for me to identify the presence of duplicate key ?

Note: there could be multiple OS_Node1\2\3\ entries.. need to identify duplicates in each of them ?

Is there any JSON api that can be used? or need to use logic based on `substring()` ?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use [`GroovyRecognizer`'](https://javadepend.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/inside-groovy/) or [`GroovyLexer`](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/859001) to parse the code.

Comment: what do you mean by `identify duplicate`?

Comment: or ose astbuilder: `new AstBuilder().buildFromString(CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS, false, '[a:1,b:2,a:3]')`

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this could be to cheat a little and replace colons with commas which would transform the maps into lists and then do a recursive search for duplicates:

```
def str = "['OS_Node':['eth0':'1310','eth0':'1312'], 'OS_Node':['eth1':'1310','eth1':'1312']]"

def tree = Eval.me(str.replaceAll(":", ","))

def dupes = findDuplicates(tree)
dupes.each { println it }

def findDuplicates(t, path=[], dupes=[]) {
  def seen = [] as Set
  t.collate(2).each { k, v -> 
    if (k in seen) dupes << [path: path + k]
    seen << k
    if (v instanceof List) findDuplicates(v, path+k, dupes)
  }
  
  dupes
}
```

when run, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
[path:[OS_Node, eth0]]
[path:[OS_Node]]
[path:[OS_Node, eth1]]
```

i.e. the method finds all paths to duplicated keys where "path" is defined as the key sequence required to navigate to the duplicate key.

The function returns a list of maps which you can then do whatever you wish with. Should be noted that the "OS_Node" key is with this logic treated as a duplicate but you could easily filter that out as a step after this function call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the string you have there is not JSON - not only due to
the duplicate keys, but also by the use of `[]` for maps.  This looks
a lot more like a groovy map literal.  So if this is your custom format
and you can not do anything against it, I'd write a small parser for this,
because sooner or later edge cases or quoting problems come around the
corner.

```
@Grab("com.github.petitparser:petitparser-core:2.3.1")
import org.petitparser.tools.GrammarDefinition
import org.petitparser.tools.GrammarParser
import org.petitparser.parser.primitive.CharacterParser as CP
import org.petitparser.parser.primitive.StringParser as SP
import org.petitparser.utils.Functions as F

class MappishGrammerDefinition extends GrammarDefinition {
    MappishGrammerDefinition() {
        define("start", ref("map"))
        define("map",
                CP.of("[" as Character)
                .seq(ref("kv-pairs"))
                .seq(CP.of("]" as Character))
                .map{ it[1] })
        define("kv-pairs",
                ref("kv-pair")
                .plus()
                .separatedBy(CP.of("," as Character))
                .map{ it.collate(2)*.first()*.first() })
        define("kv-pair",
                ref('key')9
                .seq(CP.of(":" as Character))
                .seq(ref('val'))
                .map{ [it[0], it[2]] })
        define("key", 
                ref("quoted"))
        define("val", 
                ref("quoted")
                .or(ref("map")))
        define("quoted",
                CP.anyOf("'")
                .seq(SP.of("\\''").or(CP.pattern("^'")).star().flatten())
                .seq(CP.anyOf("'"))
                .map{ it[1].replace("\\'", "'") })
    }

    // Helper for `def`, which is a keyword in groovy
    void define(s, p) { super.def(s,p) }
}

println(new GrammarParser(new MappishGrammerDefinition()).parse("['OS_Node':['eth0':'1310','eth0':'1312'],'OS_Node':['eth0':'42']]").get())
// → [[OS_Node, [[eth0, 1310], [eth0, 1312]]], [OS_Node, [[eth0, 42]]]]
```